# firebase analytics flutter don't show any result even after 2 days. Returns message like `Waiting for Analytics data...`

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, firebase-analytics

I am working on a flutter application where I have to use the firebase analytics in my app.
I have gonna through the [firebase flutter doc](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/analytics/overview/), I have implemented these to my application two days before. Still, I didn't get any events or analytics data on the console.

Please consider the following steps I have taken to implement on my project.

1. Added these dependencies to my `pubspec.yaml` file:

`firebase_analytics: ^8.1.2`
`firebase_core: ^1.3.0`

2. on my `android/build.graddle` file:

   ```
    buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.5.1'
    }
   ```
3. On my `app/build.graddle` file:

   `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`
   `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'`
4. Added my `google-services.json` file on app folder inside `android` package,
5. on `main.dart`:

   `static FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();`
   `static FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer = FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics);`
6. On builder class:

   ```
   return MaterialApp(
              navigatorObservers: [
                FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics),
              ],
   ```
7. On Every screen added this:

   `FirebaseAnalytics().setCurrentScreen(screenName: 'Splash Screen');`

Even after implementing this was getting `Waiting for Analytics data...` on the firebase console.

Can any one please let me know what is something I am doing wrong, I just need default firebase analytics data, there is no need for implementing custom events?